# Powershell AD automatic creation of guest users

Tags: powershell

Ok, so i have this project at school going where i am creating a script out from a .CSV file, and my instructor told me that i should try to create guest users if the file is empty and such.

After that i created so that i could create x amount of guest users with the script, and if i create 10 guest users, they will be named like "guest1" "guest2" and so on and so forth.
My instructor then asked me what if i ran it again, and i obviously got a lot of errors, since user 1..10 already exists.

now, i've been struggling for a couple of days to find out how to make it check what the last user is numbered as, and then continue from that point on, so if i run the script and create guest1 -> guest 10, and run it again, then it will create guest11 -> guest20.

right now my code looks like this:

```
if($users -eq "NULL"){
   $path     = "OU=test,DC=test,DC=local"
   $username = read-host "Input your ADUser name here"
   $count    = 1

   For($count; $count -ge $count + 10 ; $count++){
      New-ADUser `
      -Name $Username$Count `
      -Path $path `
      -enabled $true `
      -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
      -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $defpassword -asplaintext -force) `
      -passthru
    }
}
```

the $defpassword is just a variable i made with the password so i didn't have to write it all the time, and it all works.

the code above is what i got some help from a programmer (though who never have done any powershell work, but he is really good at programming), yet, for some reason this doesn't really do anything. when i run it, it just asks for the ADUser name, which i give it, and then it just ends the script there without creating the guest users.

either way, my code before my friend came to help me, was this:

```
$count = 1..10

foreach($i in $count){
  -Name $Username$i `
      -Path $path `
      -enabled $true `
      -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
      -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $defpassword -asplaintext -force) `
      -passthru
```

and this creates the guest users successfully, but alas, without it being able to continue onworth from the last created users, without me changing the $count to be 11..20, and so forth.

Sidenote: all the variables in the second code snipp is the same as in the first, just didn't include them cause they're all on another pc, and i can't copy so had to write it in hand here, and was too lazy to write all the variables again.

Can anybody help me with how to make it continue its counting with users? like, how is the code supposed to be showcased for me to just keep running the code to constantly create 10 new guest users without the need for me to change anything in the script?

Comment: Hint: see [example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) about `Get-ADUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the modified script:

```
$i=1
for(){
$n="guest$($i)"
if(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like $n"){$i++}else{break}}
$x=$i+9
$path = "OU=test,DC=test,DC=local"
$username = read-host "Input your ADUser name here"
($i)..($x)|%{
      New-ADUser `
      -Name "$($Username)$($_)" `
      -Path $path `
      -enabled $true `
      -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
      -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $defpassword -asplaintext -force) `
      -passthru
}
```

It will first check if guestN user exist, Where N will increment from 1, and while checking, if not found break the loop and start creating new users.

Comment: when i run this code i get constantly errors.
the errors i get says:

Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'name -like guest1(guest1)' Error Message_ 'syntax error'

Comment: Please now check without the sub-exp operators, currently I am unable to check it in AD environment